# SSIS output date as DD/MM/YYY 00:00:00

Tags: sql-server, csv, datetime, ssis, etl

I'm trying to import an excel file which has a column with a custom date format of "dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00" and export it into a csv file in the same format.

The flat file is currently converting the date to DT_DATE and not displaying the time stamp (which is always 00:00:00)

I've haven't dealt much with date conversion, therefore unsure how best to approach this, although I have tried a number of things before resulting to this post, with no luck.

Any help appreciated

Thank you

Comment: I don't work much with Excel files - almost always CSV. With that being said, what is the data type for the CSV output file for that column? You can get this by opening the connection manager and selecting the `Advanced` window. Try using DT_DBTIMESTMP.

Comment: just map it to the destination without doing any conversion or derived column. I think you got a good answer

Comment: @DAVE1816 if this answer solved the issue then you must mark it as accepted and upvote it. not just saying Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When storing data in a flat file, you don't need to specify the column data type as DT_DATE, **leave it as DT_WSTR and map it with the input column**.

Note that DT_DATE can be implicitly converted to DT_WSTR, You can learn more about allowed converion in the following link:

- [Data type conversion (Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017#implicit-and-explicit-conversion)

Changing the data type will not change anything inside the flat file because it is just a metadata information needed by SSIS package.

---

*Side Note: To change the column data type, open the flat file connection manager, go to Advanced Tab, select the column and change the data type from the properties grid.*

Comment: So to be clear, in the flat file my Date Column data type is DT_WSTR and in source advanced editor  Source output both External and Output are set as DT_Date (Note these have not been altered by me). The result still shows "27/02/2019" and not "27/02/2019 00:00:00". Have I missed something?

Comment: @DAVE1816 Try converting the value to DT_DBTIMESTMP and map it to the flat file

Comment: I think I tried that and got only DD/MM/YY "HH:MM", missing the "SS" ,I will retry and confirm. Thanks

Comment: Now I recall that worked however I get 2019-02-27 00:00:00, any idea how I would get it back to DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS.

Comment: Also if my time stamp was 23:00:00 this would show, it just doesn't show 00:00:00, which is my permanent time stamp

Comment: Done! :) So I've created a derived column and  converted the DT_DATE to string and + "00:00:00" time stamp at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your help!